# Finding the P-value of a 2-sided F-test

Tags: statistics

[image]

So I believe that since I am given variances, I use F-distribution in order to test statistic. But I am a little bit confused how to find p-values for this question.. correct me if I am wrong in the first place Thanks!

Comment: You are correct that there is a little more to getting the P-value of a 2-sided F-test than is revealed in R output for the test. See explanation in my Answer.

Comment: oh thank you! so there is no way for me to get this p-value without using R right? because this is one of the Final Exam question

Comment: R or a statistical calculator for an exact value. You might be able to bracket the P-value using a printed table. My printed F-table puts prob .25 above 1.64 and prob ,10 above 2.59 in the upper tail. That tells you _something_ about the upper tail probability above 1.71. Then double that. Anyhow, at least it's good enough so you know you can't reject $H_0.$ General speaking, P-values are 'creatures' of the computer age. // Why not check _exact_ wording of the problem and try to say something that shows you understand the issues involved. // My goal to teach you something, not to work exm prb.

Answer (score 2):

First I repeat the computation of the test statistic. With sample sizes of 9 in each group you have $S_R^2 = 6.335$ and $S_W^2 = 10.8375,$ so $F = 6.335/10.8375 =  0.5845.$  Under $H_0: \sigma_R^2/\sigma_W^2 = 1.$ the variance ratio
$F \sim \mathsf{F}(8,8).$

The graph below shows the situation. (Notice that the observed F-ratio is
near the mode of the F-distribution, so we cannot expect to reject $H_0.)$

[image]

First, let's get the P-value *using* R. Then figure out how R did the computation.

```
r = c(3.5, 8.1, 7.4, 4.0, 0.7, 4.9, 8.4, 7.0, 5.5)
w = c(3.1, 0.5, -3.8, 4.1,-0.6, 2.7, 1.9, -5.9, 0.1)
var.test(r, w)

        F test to compare two variances

data:  r and w
F = 0.58454, num df = 8, denom df = 8, p-value = 0.4643
alternative hypothesis: true ratio of variances is not equal to 1
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.1318543 2.5914373
sample estimates:
ratio of variances 
         0.5845444
```

So the P-value is 0.4643. The P-value is defined as a the probability
of getting a result that is 'as or more extreme' than the observed F-ratio.
Because this is a two-sided test, 'extreme' values can be found in both
tails of the F-distribution.

Using R as a statistical calculator, we have $P(F < .5845) = 0.2321.$
This is the area under the density curve above to the left of the vertical
black bar.

```
pf(.5845, 8, 8)
## 0.2321101
```

You can find this value on many statistical calculators, but not in an
ordinary printed F-table, because (in order to save space) such table 
show only upper tail probabilities.

*But this is a two-sided test,* so there is another part to the P-value. We might have formed the variance ratio
as $F' = 10.8375/6.335 =  1.711.$ Depending on the printed table you use,
you might be able to estimate the *other part* of the P-value
$P(F > 1.711) = 0.2321.$ Certainly, you could get this probability on
a statistical calculator programmed to give F probabilities. This is
the probability to the right of the vertical red broken line in the
figure below.

```
1 - pf(1.711, 8, 8)
## 0.2320774
```

[image]

Thus the P-value is the *sum of the two tail probabilities:*
$0.2321 + 0.2321 = 0.4642,$ which is essentially the same
as in the R output from the variance test.

*Note:* If sample sizes are unequal, components of the P-value in
the two tails may not be exactly equal, as they were here.
Perhaps see [*this Q & A*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2721335/critical-values-of-f-statistic-for-two-tailed-test/2721543#2721543) for more on this topic.